# How to remove a node from a Flow Pane in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

I created an array of HBoxes, Buttons and Labels. Each time an 'Add' button is pressed,
I set:

```
hbox[count] = new HBox();
buttons[count] = new Button();
labels[count] = new Label();
```

(where count starts at 0 and ends at 5)
I then add the button and the label to the HBox (so that each HBox contains a button and a Label) and finally add the 5 HBoxes to a Flow Pane.
**How can I delete an HBox from the Flow Pane by clicking the button inside the HBox?**[image]
*This is a picture of each of the HBoxes in the Flow Pane.*

```
/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author HeshamSaleh
 */
public class SecondaryViewController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TextField searchBar;
@FXML
private Button addBtn;
@FXML
private FlowPane flowPane;

ArrayList<String> addedArtists = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] artists = {"Craig David", "Coldplay", "Eminem", "D12", "Shakira", "Radiohead", "Linkin Park", "Maroon 5", "Celine Dion", "50 Cent", "Tupac", "Snoop Dogg", "Metallica", "Backstreet Boys"};
List<String> artistNames  = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(artists));
int count = 4;
HBox[] hboxArr = new HBox[5];
Button[] buttonArr = new Button[5];
Label[] labelArr = new Label[5];
int hboxCount = 0;
/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    searchBar.setFocusTraversable (false);
    TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(searchBar, artistNames);
}   

@FXML
private void addBtnPressed(MouseEvent event) {
    String artistName = searchBar.getText();
    searchBar.setText("");

    if(artistNames.contains(artistName) && !addedArtists.contains(artistName) && count != -1) {

        hboxArr[hboxCount] = new HBox();
        buttonArr[hboxCount] = new Button();
        labelArr[hboxCount] = new Label();
        hboxArr[hboxCount].setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hboxArr[hboxCount].setSpacing(-1);
        buttonArr[hboxCount].setText("X");
        buttonArr[hboxCount].setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        buttonArr[hboxCount].setStyle("-fx-background-color: TRANSPARENT; -fx-border-color: #000000;");
        buttonArr[hboxCount].setFont(Font.font("Open Sans", FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
        buttonArr[hboxCount].setMinWidth(20);
        buttonArr[hboxCount].setMinHeight(20);
        labelArr[hboxCount].setText(artistName.toUpperCase());
        labelArr[hboxCount].setFont(Font.font("Proxima Nova Rg", 12));
        labelArr[hboxCount].setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        labelArr[hboxCount].setStyle("-fx-background-color: TRANSPARENT; -fx-border-color: #000000;");
        labelArr[hboxCount].setMinWidth(90);
        labelArr[hboxCount].setMinHeight(27);

        hboxArr[hboxCount].getChildren().addAll(buttonArr[hboxCount], labelArr[hboxCount]);
        flowPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        flowPane.getChildren().add(hboxArr[hboxCount]);
        addedArtists.add(artistName);
        count--;
        hboxCount++;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example... you can take the idea of the implementation and apply it to your program :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application{

    ArrayList<Node> components = new ArrayList<Node>(); // arraylist to contain all components


    @Override
    public void start(Stage ps) throws Exception {
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){

            HBox hb = new HBox();
            // set hb attributes

            Button b = new Button("Button" + i);
            // set b attributes

            // then add action listener
            b.setOnAction(e->{ 
                root.getChildren().remove(hb); // remove by Object reference
            });

            Label l = new Label("Label" + i);
            // set l attributes

            hb.getChildren().addAll(b,l);
            components.add(hb);
        }

        root.getChildren().addAll(components);

        Scene s = new Scene(root, 600,400);
        ps.setScene(s);

        ps.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

After you provided the code, all you need to do is to add this to your code:

```
buttonArr[hboxCount].setOnAction(e->{ // add listener to your button at every index in your array of buttons
    flowPane.getChildren().remove(hboxArr[hboxCount]); // and when that button is pressed, remove the HBox at the same index in the array of HBoxs from the flowPane (that works as I said -> removing by Object Reference)
});
```

Comment: How would you know which hb you are removing? I need to remove a specific hb when its button is pressed

Comment: @HeshamSaleh Akhi it removes the HBox (i.e. parent) of the Button Pressed.. please copy-paste the code in your IDE and check :)

Comment: Ok, your code does exactly what I need. Can you please help me implement it in my code above? Thanks a lot Yahya!